# Getting line integral from parametrised equations

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am currently doing this question from a book and I seem to be getting different answeres than the ones specified.
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGUAm.png)

My current working is as follows
$$
\vec F=(2t^3+3)\vec i+2t^5\vec j+(t^4-2t^2)\vec k
$$
$$
\vec r=2t^2\vec i+t\vec j+t^3\vec k
$$

$$
dr =4t+1+3t^2 dt
$$

$$
\int_C\vec F.dr = \int_0^1(2t^3+3)(4t)+2t^5+(t^4-2t^2)3t^2 dt = \frac{752}{105} =7.162
$$
while the answer from the book says **288/35** approx **8.229**
Can you help me pinpoint where I went wrong?

Comment: $$
\vec F=(2t+3)\vec i+2t^5\vec j+(t^4-2t^2)\vec k$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\vec F=(2t+3)\vec i+2t^5\vec j+(t^4-2t^2)\vec k$$

$$
\int_C\vec F.dr = \int_0^1(2t+3)(4t)+2t^5+(t^4-2t^2)3t^2 dt = \frac{288}{35}$$